# Access ApiController User in class library

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, iprincipal

I have a Web API 2.2 application and want to filter data based on the current user that is accessing the Web API. The User property on the ApiController has the information that I need. But how can I get that information to my service class? Of course I don't want to pass everything around via parameters, but via my DI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass your principal into the methods of the service class, not as a constructor parameter.  Depending on how you are using DI, that service class can hang around for a while, and you don't want the class to have the principal in that case.  You want your principal to be short lived.

Comment: Good point. Somebody in the future might decide to change DI behaviour or a bug might come along. Better to have it short lived.